# Django channels file/image upload

Tags: websocket, upload, django-channels

I would like to upload files and images using [django-channels](https://github.com/django/channels/) but i don't have any idea where to start. Seems like there is not much documentation about websockets and file/image uploads. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you couldn't accomplish this with AJAX? One issue with Django channels is that the maximum message size is 1MB, so for a robust solution, you'd also have to break the file into chunks, then reassemble them server-side.

Comment: Ajax or using 3rd party packages would suffice. They are also quite a number of plugins for django for uploading images directly to s3.  https://github.com/sbc/django-uploadify-s3

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes since the django-channels or better the daphne server has a max package size of 1mb i've junked the file in javascript and uploaded it using a  file upload consumer.

Comment: @PyUnchained I don't think Channels has a max message size. I think its only determined by Redis. IMO its better to do the uploads with Channels because you can chunk it out and show a progress bar.

Comment: @PyUnchained but how to show it to the user again?

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the same problem and I solved it by uploading the the Image/File in S3 bucket. we just need to decode the base64 code and upload the file and return the URL to websocket. We can also provide preview of the image by providing the file type.

```
def file_upload(self, data):
    # Convert decode the base64 data 
    file = base64.b64decode(data['data']['content'].split(',')[-1])
    filename = data['data']['filename']
    type = data['data']['type']
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = getattr(settings, "AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = getattr(settings, "AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
    bucket_name = getattr(settings, "AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME")
    conn = boto.connect_s3(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
    bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    k = Key(bucket)
    k.key = getattr(settings, "AWS_CHAT_DIR") + '/' + filename
    k.set_metadata('Content-Type', type)
    k.set_contents_from_string(file)
    url = 'https://' + getattr(settings, "AWS_BUCKET_URL") + '/' + k.key
    message = url
    content = {
        'command': 'new_message',
        'message': self.message_to_json(message)
    }
    return self.send_chat_message(content)
```

Comment: what is the data here you accept as argument to the file_upload function? can you post that part of your code as well?

Answer (score 2):

The only real way to do this is with Channels 2 because the consumers persist for the duration of the session and you can put a file object on it as an instance variable.

You can see how I use the file field and first send some initialization parameters on it. I pulled out the important parts:

```js
// Some class setup before this

// File field object
this.file = field.files[0];
init_params.action = 'prepare';
init_params.file_name = this.file.name;
init_params.file_size = this.file.size;

// This is a wrapper I have that gets a websocket. 
// The callback is called on connect. It sends the initialization parameters.
var ws = get_websocket(url, function(){
    this.send(JSON.stringify(init_params));
});

// After the initialization params are sent this is called with 0 as a parameter. 
// As the web server oks each chunk this is called with the next offset to send. chunk_size needs to be set somewhere.
var load_data = function(index) {
    var end =  index + this.chunk_size;
    if (index >= this.file.size)
        return;
    if (end > this.file.size)
        end = this.file.size;
    ws.send(this.file.slice(index, end));
}.bind(this);

ws.onmessage = function(msg) {
    var message = JSON.parse(msg.data);
    switch (message.action) {
        case 'progress':
            // This is called each time a chunk is written
            load_data(message.file_size);
            break;
        case 'ready':
            // This comes in to kick everything off
            load_data(0);
            break;
        case 'complete':
            // Handle complete
            break;
            }
        };
    }.bind(this);
```

In the consumer we check if it is text data and if it is we process it as JSON to set up the file. If its binary data we write each chunk out like this.

```py
    async def handle_json(self, message):
         self.session = {
             # Set up file object and attributes
         }

    async def handle_chunk(self, message, **kwargs):
        upload_size = self.session.get('upload_size')
        temp_destination = self.session.get('upload_file')

        if not upload_size or not temp_destination:
            return self.error('Invalid request. Please try again.')

        self.session['upload_file'].write(message)
        size = self.session['upload_file'].tell()

        percent = round((size / upload_size) * 100)
        await self.send_json({
            'action': 'progress',
            'percent': percent,
            'file_size': size
        })

        if size >= upload_size:
            self.session['upload_file'].flush()
            file_name = await self.handle_complete(self.session['upload_file'])

            await self.send_json({
                'action': 'complete',
                'file_size': size,
                'file_name': file_name
            }, close=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy Approach is to use FileReader. On Client Side you will have the following code.

```
//connect the websocket with server
var client = new WebSocket('ws://hostname')

//now get the base64 src for image for it i have 
  written a function.

function toDataURL(file, callback) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function () {
        var dataURL = reader.result;
        callback(dataURL);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

document.getElementById('image').addEventListener('change', function(event){
    var files = event.target
    var file = files[0];
    toDataURL(file, function(dataURL){
    client.send(JSON.stringify({
        'command':'new_file', 
        'dataURL': dataURL
    }))
    })
})
```

this will send the dataURL to your Consumer and then from there you can send it to the group i.e. to all users and can use this dataURL as src of image to show the image on browser:)

for example:

```
<img src=dataURL>
```

you can create this using javascript function for example you can use document.createElement('img') and provide the src as dataURL with javascript.