# File upload with Django Channels 2

Tags: django, socket.io, django-rest-framework, django-channels

I am creating a chat application using Channels 2, I have been able to implement a one-one chat plus a chat room but just cannot figure out how to handle file uploads. Any idea would go a long way

Comment: maybe the method mentioned on the link might work.
[django-channels file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41492493/django-channels-file-image-upload?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by creating a different endpoint that uploads the file and send a socket request to the listening clients with the file link and file type.